# Getting file format exception while trying to import CSV into hive

Tags: csv, hive

I have a Hive table with the following structure:

```
app_id                  string                                      
platform                string                                      
app_name                string                                      
developer_name          string                                      
rating                  double                                      
category_csv            string                                      
num_ratings             bigint                                      
num_recommendations     bigint                                      
num_downloads           bigint                                      
size_mbs                double                                      
price                   double                                      
in_app_purchase_confidence  double                                      
content_maturity        string                                      
badges_csv              string                                      
bundle_id               string                                      
rfi_brand_rating        string                                      
category_id_csv         string                                      
country_code            string                                      
permissions             string
```

I am trying to import the following one line CSV into it (which has tab separated values):

```
1000011509  IOS Emily+Grows+Up+-+Journey+from+Birth+to+Adulthood    Ninjafish+Studios   Games,Role-Playing,Family   0   0   0   0   59  0   1   4+  iosUniversal    com.ninjafishstudios.emilygrowsup       6014,7014,7009  MY  abc
```

I am using the following command:

```
hive -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/usernamehere/a0/a1/new' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mobile_repo;"
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.
>       18/03/30 12:05:39 ERROR exec.Task: Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.
>       org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.

Can someone please tell me what's the problem ?

EDIT: The table I'm trying to import into was created using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE mobile_repo (app_id string, platform string, app_name string, developer_name string, rating double, category_csv string, num_ratings bigint, num_recommendations bigint, num_downloads bigint, size_mbs double, price double, in_app_purchase_confidence double, content_maturity string, badges_csv string, bundle_id string, rfi_brand_rating string, category_id_csv string, country_code string, permissions string);
```

Comment: Don't you have to mention the file-format in the path?

Comment: how did you specify row format and delimiters when creating the table? can you show them as well?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I have added the command I used to create the table

Answer (score 0):

Specify the delimiter when creating the table so when you `load` data from a file it will be parsed accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE mobile_repo 
(app_id string, platform string, app_name string, developer_name string, 
 rating double, category_csv string, num_ratings bigint, num_recommendations bigint,
 num_downloads bigint, size_mbs double, price double, in_app_purchase_confidence double, 
 content_maturity string, badges_csv string, bundle_id string, rfi_brand_rating string, 
 category_id_csv string, country_code string, permissions string)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\t'
location 'specify a HDFS location'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too:

```
Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Wrong file format. Please
check the file's format.
```

and I found I created table with "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'", but actually the delimiter of my data is ',' , I actually dropped that table and created it again with "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','", and it loads data rightly.

hope this will be helpful.